# Jetty passing bad NIO Argument to Java (or a JVM bug)

Tags: java, jetty, nio

I am getting a very deep and cryptic error from Jetty, and the SelectorManager code indicates it may be a bug in the JVM.

The exception is coming from `sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl`, which seems like a JVM impl class.

So I tested with both sun JVM and OpenJDK, same error.

Anybody have any ideas?

```
2011-01-06 12:22:26.183:INFO::jetty-8.0.0.M1
2011-01-06 12:22:26.374:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:11309
2011-01-06 12:22:26.708:WARN::EXCEPTION 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:11309]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.accept(SelectChannelConnector.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:793)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Is this happening all the time or intermittently? At server startup?

Comment: `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:11309` looks suspiciously like a bad IPv6 address:port.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: no it's not, it's just the IPv6 version of INADDR_ANY.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the program with enough privileges to bind to 0.0.0.0?

Can you try binding to a specific IP address?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (on Jetty 7.3.1), it turns out I was loading two different versions of Jetty. (one through a maven dependency). I excluded jetty 7.2 and all was well in the land of Jetty.

Good luck.